# How to customize Login given by Auth0?

Tags: auth0

Is it possible to customize the login page provided by Auth0 in the free tier? If yes, how can I modify the login page to add my own branding, change the layout and design, and add custom functionality using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript? Are there any limitations to the customization options available in the free tier?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is Both Yes and No.

1. Customize the login page -> Yes, you can do this with the free tier.
2. Modifying HTML, CSS, JS -> No, you cannot do this with the free tier. You need to have custom domain.

### How to Customize login page

Navigate to **Branding -> Universal Login -> Select Customization Options**. You can customize the pages with the given tools

[image]

[image]

Also you can edit the Prompts and Error, warning text via **Branding -> Universal Login -> Select Advanced Options**.

[image]

[image]

### How to Customize HTML, CSS, and JS

**In the free tier you cannot do this**. You need to have a custom domain. Navigate to **Branding -> Custom Domains** to get more info.

[image]